# php date picker web browsers

Tags: php, html, date, datepicker

I am working on a simple date picker which show todays date as a default. The problem is that I cant make it work same on different browsers as Chrome, firefox and Opera.

```
<?php
  $timezone = "Europe/Oslo";
  date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
  $today = date("d.m.Y");
echo $today." <br>";
?>

<html>
  <body>
    <input type="date" value="<?php echo $today ?>">
  </body>
</html>
```

Google Chrome:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

Opera:

[image]

As you can see in firefox i get the date, but not in GC or Opera.

But when I format the date as: `$today = date("Y-m-d");`

It looks like this in Google Chrome:

[image]

Opera:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

input type="date" is not supported in firefox so it takes the value just as a text 
and in chrome default format is dd/mm/yyyy

in opera default format is mm/dd/yyyy

if you just want to display the date change the type to text will support any format

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $today ?>">
```

Comment: With that, it will lose this possibily to be a datepicker: http://i.imgur.com/HJBPmlo.png

Comment: ok.. but it ( date type ) will not support in browsers like firefox and IE ,check jquery datepicker it will support all formats and will suport in all browsers http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

The date type is not yet supported by FireFox.

For Chrome and Opera, you can format like this:

```
$ today = date ("Y-m-d");
```

To determine the browser and adjust your display you can use this [method](https://www.php.net/get_browser#101125)

You can also use a date picker js such as [JQuery](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)